# Spring constructor injection and super call verbosity

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I started to use constructor injection in my projects since Spring declared field injection to be deprecated. Actually, the code feels prettier and more strict, I'm ok with that.
But I encountered a pattern which seems a bit...weird and verbose to me:

I have an abstract service bean class (with `@Service` annotation), which has, say 2 dependencies, injected directly in the constructor:

```
@Autowired
public AbstractService(DependencyA depA, DependencyB depB) {
    this.depA = depA;
    this.depB = depB;
}
```

Then I have multiple services bean classes (still with `@Service`annotation) extending the abstract one.
And I don't know if there is another way but this is where I find a bit verbose and repetitive having to inject the dependencies for the parent, in each sub-class constructor:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA extends AbstractService {
    private final DepC depC;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceA(DepA depA, DepB depB, DepC depC) {
        super(depA, depB);
        this.depC = depC;
    }

}
```

I just wanted to know if this is the right way, and what you think about this ?

Comment: why should it be verbose or reptitive. Yeah for classes with only one possible constructor you could argue so, but what if there would be multiple different overloaded constructors in `AbstractService`, how would `ServiceA` determine which one to call. But yes that´s the right way.

Comment: The `@Autowired` on `AbstractService` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I cannot see why do you need to annotate you abstract constructor with `@Autowired`. It's not needed since you fields will be injected into you super class constructor. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 4):

The `@Autowired` on `AbstractService` doesn't do anything. Change it to:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA extends AbstractService {
    private final DepC depC;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceA(DepA depA, DepB depB, DepC depC) {
        super(depA, depB);
        this.depC = depC;
    }
}

...

public AbstractService(DependencyA depA, DependencyB depB) {
    this.depA = depA;
    this.depB = depB;
}
```

I'm ok with this setup.

**For me, the main benefits** of using constructor injection is to inform the developer what are the external dependencies. I find it useful when writing unit test. When writing mocks, you just know what needs to be mocked.

An **other benefit** is to highlight when a Class has too many dependencies, it gives a hint that refactoring may be in order.

The **alternative** would be using setter injection (while keeping the informational aspect), but I've grown to enjoy constructor injection.

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Setter injection would be a solution but I prefer constructor injection for the fact that fields can be `final`.
And I never thought about removing the `@Autowired` annotation from the superclass constructor, but it makes sense now I see your code.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is focusing about the "verbose and repetitive" part in your question; I let others decide how "correct" your usage of annotations is.

Even with Spring and its DI framework, in the end we are still talking about **Java** source code!

And in Java, if your base class **only** offers a constructor that takes some A and B; then **of course** your subclass has to make a call super(A a, B b); and of course, those values a and b have to come from somewhere!

So, what you call "verbose and repetitive" is a direct consequence of using Java.

In other words: there is no way to avoid that part!